# git diff renamed file in index against HEAD

Tags: git

I have a file in my repo.  I renamed this file with git mv.  Then I made some edits.  I have not committed anything.  So when I run git status, it shows the rename in my index as:

```
renamed: A.txt -> B.txt
```

I would like to diff the changes in my index, in the file B.txt, against the HEAD revision of a.txt.  How can I do this?  I've found some similar questions that were answered by mentioning the -M option, but both were regarding the situation where you are diffing one commit against another commit.  Not staged changes in your index against a commit.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work as expected for me. Console.log below. Maybe I am misunderstanding something. I also show my git version.

```
➜  xg git:(home) ✗ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ~/xg/.git/
➜  xg git:(master) echo cool > a.txt
➜  xg git:(master) ✗ git add .
➜  xg git:(master) ✗ git commit -m cool
[master (root-commit) 93c4809] cool
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 a.txt
➜  xg git:(master) git mv a.txt b.txt
➜  xg git:(master) ✗ ls
b.txt
➜  xg git:(master) ✗ echo beans >> b.txt 
➜  xg git:(master) ✗ git diff
diff --git a/b.txt b/b.txt
index 2b58f89..56b656c 100644
--- a/b.txt
+++ b/b.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 cool
+beans
➜  xg git:(master) ✗ git --version
git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)
➜  xg git:(master) ✗
```

Comment: For some reason it didn't work for me, but I did finally end up with something that works.  Refresh to see the answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally came up with a working solution.  I'm using msys git on Windows, which may or may not be related, but I coudln't get it to work with just git diff, as another poster mentioned.

git diff -M50 HEAD -- [oldpath] [newpath]

Comment: `git mv` stages the rename so a `git diff --staged` or `git difftool --staged` will show you what you need. Any changes after `git mv`, `git diff` correctly shows only the changes.